# How to replace Query URL with file location

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I have part of my code like this

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
            'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuehW_PIAYbKdEJ4bHJPNVZYTGRSQ2h5VVk4TTM1VUE');
        query.send(draw);
```

but the problem is google docs is censored in China, so I need to know how to direct the query to a file location on my computer, such as C:/....

Comment: I don't think this would be possible. For security reasons clients side code can't access files in your system. You could maybe try using another service that works in China...

Comment: Essentially, this part of the program takes the Google Docs Spreadsheet and creates a graph out of it. Is there perhaps another function I can use to the program draw out the spreadsheet that I have downloaded on my computer?

Comment: As for the other service part, I would assume it has to be similar to google docs where a link will open up a spreadsheet for you. I have never actually seen another service for documents to be viewed and edited in browsers. If you know of any, please suggest some.